# Are Unrestricted unions compatible with C?

Tags: c++, c++11

Now that C++11 allows you to create unions such as this

```
union U {
   int z;
   std::vector<char> data;
};
```

Is it possible somehow to pass this structure to C library that accepts a regular C union? How?

Comment: Won't the `std::vector<char>` be a bigger problem?

Comment: @minitech I was thinking may be you could pass the pointer like so &data[0]

Comment: @user841550 : Right, but then you're not passing an instance of the union, which begs the question...

Comment: @ildjarn You are right. I don't know the real answer, that's why I am asking. I thought the designers may have thought about some compiler magic that would allow us to pass such a union to C functions

Comment: +1 for question. Obviously C can't do anything with an instance of `U` which contains a `vector`, but it's reasonable to wonder if you can pass an instance of `U` when it contains just an `int`. Remember, C has strict layout-compatibility rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you pass *that* union? No. `std::vector` (and all other standard containers except `std::array`) will not produce types of a *known* layout. They may be [standard layout types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7189821/734069), but no particular layout is presented in the standard. Therefore, you cannot pass it to C.

Note: By "pass it to C," I assume you mean "build an equivalent C structure that has the same memory layout so that C code can touch the data."

But you can pass any union that contains types of a known layout as long as all of the types are standard layout types. They need not be trivial, but they must be standard layout.

Also, if you don't mind being compiler specific, you could look at your particular `std::vector` implementation (or use a specific implementation like `boost::vector`) and devise an equivalent C structure that stores essentially the same data. Of course, that assumes that the particular implementation is indeed standard layout; the C++ standard doesn't require it to be, and the presence of an allocator might change this.